# Why is the word not breaking to a new line in Chrome but it is in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm just creating some basic HTML/CSS. I'm creating overlay texts, buttons and text with a shaded background. However, the text in the shaded box is supposed to break to a new line when it touches the width but it doesn't in Chrome. It works in IE and FF though.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QN6NS/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="bkgrndImgExecClub">
    <div class="frameContent backgroundBox basic">
        <p>Passar pelo aeroporto com rapidez utilizando o aplicativo da Bwefwef wefwef</p>              
    </div>

    <p class="creditText">Foto por michael Chudakov Club member desde 2003</p>

    <input type="submit" value="O significado de pertencer" name="callToAction" class="button primary">     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.frameContent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    left: 30px;
    top: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.bkgrndImgExecClub {
    background-image: url(TIM_BANNERS_BLUE_LATAM_PT_TEST-IMAGE_1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 180px;
    width: 760px;
    position: relative;
}

.frameContent p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.creditText {
    right: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word; /*This doesn't seem to work in Chrome*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-size: 0.80em;
    font-weight: bold;
}



.button.primary {
    background: #ce210f;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3e3e 0%, #ce210f 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3e3e), color-stop(100%,#ce210f));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3e3e 0%,#ce210f 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3e3e 0%,#ce210f 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3e3e 0%,#ce210f 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ff3e3e 0%,#ce210f 100%);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.button {
    border: 1px solid #AE1000;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    position:absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 7.5px;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2rem;
}
```

Comment: using firefox 24 and chrome 30 your jsfiddle looks identical

Comment: Hi, the word "da" should break to a new line which it doesn't in Chrome

Comment: both of my versions have "da" as the last word of the middle line

Comment: Hmm, weird, "da" is on the last line for FF for me

Comment: Im using FF24 on Xubuntu if that helps any

Answer (score 1):

I assume your talking about the word "da" which touches the right edge of the box when looking at the example in Chrome.

How about adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.frameContent` class? The `box-sizing` property will make sure the box doesn't "grow" because of the padding on the left side. When I add this property to the JSFiddle it looks the same in both Chrome and Firefox.

I would also suggest maybe using a padding for all sides of the box (or at least the right side) instead of just the left side, to have it look consistent regardless of the text inside the box.

More on `box-sizing` here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can render fonts differently, and they'd try to break words between spaces. Your example looks normal to me. (currently breaks at space)

If you are talking about the "**ba**" not dropping to a new line and if you really need **da** and **Bwefwef** together. You can keep them together by replacing space with an

It's still gonna add a space between the two words but will make it unbreakable across browsers no matter what.

So you could have it like this:

```
<p>Passar pelo aeroporto com rapidez utilizando o aplicativo da&nbsp;Bwefwef wefwef</p>
```

or

```
<p>Passar pelo aeroporto com rapidez utilizando o aplicativo da&nbsp;Bwefwef&nbsp;wefwef</p>
```

to prevent orphans, which is also a good practice for design.

I hope this helps. :)